# Coordinate ring of the product of projective variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X\subseteq \mathbb{P}^r,Y \subseteq \mathbb{P}^s$ be two projectve varieties,what is the coordinate ring of $X\times Y$(segre embedding)?Is it true that
$$S(X\times Y)=S(X)\otimes_k S(Y)?$$

I also want to know what is the dimension of $ X\times Y$?

Edit:As Zhen Lin has indicated ,the equality $S(X\times Y)=S(X)\otimes_k S(Y)$ is not true.But what is the relationship between them,can we express $S(X\times Y)$ in terms of $S(X),S(Y)$?

Comment: Did you calculate any examples? Say, $X = Y = \mathbb{P}^1$?

Comment: I know that $S(\mathbb{P}^1)=k[x,y]$,but what is $S(\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1)$?

Comment: It doesn't matter. $S (\mathbb{P}^1) \otimes_k S (\mathbb{P}^1)$ is then $k [x, y, z, w]$ with the usual grading, and so the associated projective variety is $\mathbb{P}^3$, which doesn't even have the correct dimension.

Comment: Note that it doesn't make sense to talk about *the* coordinate ring, as it is not unique for a given projective variety. As you mentionned Segre embedding, I guess you want to decribe $S(X\times Y)$ as a quotient of the canonical coordinte ring of $\mathbb P^{rs+r+s-1}$ ?

Comment: @Cantlog:Yes.I also want to know the dimension of $X\times Y$.

Comment: @WeiXia: as a general fact, the dimension of the product of two algebraic varieties is always the sum of the dimensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that the coordinate ring for $X\times Y$ is

$$S(X\times Y) = \bigoplus_{i} S(X)_i\otimes S(Y)_i \subset S(X)\otimes S(Y)$$

where $S(X)_i$ is the degree $i$ component of $S(X)$.

Exercise 13.14 in Eisenbud's Commutative Algebra text goes through this fact.

Comment: Thanks!what about the dimension of $X\times Y$?

Comment: You can also see the dimension computations in the reference I mentioned.